# Cost of importing libraries

Tags: android

I've been working on an Android app project. I'm using quite a few libraries (because why redo work that someone else has done to make other people's life easier?).

My question is: **what are the costs of importing libraries in a project**? (I'm talking about the `implementation XXX.YYY:v2.0.0` type of line added in the `build.gradle` dependencies list.)

Just as an example (though please provide a more encompassing answer): when compiling and publishing my application, does it take all of the libraries' classes and methods and put them in my application, thus making it much heavier than it would need to be?

Comment: "does it take all of the libraries' classes and methods and put them in my application, thus making it much heavier than it would need to be?" -- by default, yes, at least for `debug` builds. You can [configure Gradle to "minify" your `release` builds](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code), removing unused classes as best it can.

Comment: I've never really used `ProGuards`: the obfuscation features and what not are applied to the current project when the build is ran? Does this mean I could accidentally end up with an overwritten version that would be hard to work with because of those feature?

Comment: "the obfuscation features and what not are applied to the current project when the build is ran?" -- yes, though you can block the obfuscation part, if you do not want that. "Does this mean I could accidentally end up with an overwritten version that would be hard to work with because of those feature?" -- I do not know what you mean by "overwritten" here. Your `debug` and `release` builds result in separate APKs. If you use an `applicationIdSuffix`, you can even have `debug` and `release` have separate application IDs, so they could be installed at the same time.

Comment: I've never yet released anything, hence why I lack understanding and knowledge in this field. This is my first Android project. `debug` build is basically what I'm using currently to develop the project, and `release` will literally be something generated from the `debug`, but targeting some other place in my computer's memory (thus creating a separate project I could work with, aside from the `debug` one... "kind of" like a Git-branch)?

Comment: `debug` and `release` are pre-defined [build types](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types). Typically, `debug` is what you build for day-to-day development, and `release` is what you ship to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each library dependency requires an additional download while you compile your app. So these will increase the amount of time required to compile.
2. The code for each library is included in your final APK so they will increase the size.

Comment: So including something like `Firebase` or `Spring` dependencies greatly increases the size of the app that will be released in the Google Play Store? How to avoid such a thing? And when a library is decently simple, how ethical is it to just go take the classes and methods that we need from it to avoid importing the whole thing?

Comment: How to avoid such a thing? You analyze if you really need the functionality in the code, if not, you don't use the lib, if yes you use it and don't think about it anymore, it is how it is.To your last question, this is not an ethical question, if the license of the lib allows it you can modify whatever you want at your own risk, but this is not recommended as libs gets updates often and you don't want to make your changes each time!

Comment: Maybe you could clear a slight confusion from my part: if I add a dependency in the gradle, but do not import any of its components/modules, does it still count toward increasing the size of the app? ("import as in the `import X.Y.Z` line at the very top of a class in my project.)

Comment: @payne I don't know if the Android build tools chain is intelligent enough to only include the classes which you use. One solution is to enable Proguard to minify and obfuscate your code. This will remove unused classes and methods from your final APK.

Comment: `minify` would basically only keep the code that is used by my project, but would that be for example the WHOLE class that contains the one method I use in it, or is it more intelligent about it and would create a new class in my project with only the necessary methods?

Comment: @payne I'm not sure about the details of `minify`. Even if it keeps each class in which you use at least one method, it still throws away all the classes which you don't use at all, so there should be a significant savings.

Answer (score 1):

For Every Library a download is necessary In order to built your app. 
e.g If you want Libraries regarding to Firebase then You download the Library by adding the Firebase Project to your App. In `build.gradle` File you see the dependencies after you add them to Your Project App.